# Create Dataframe from List & Pivot, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have below list & want to convert ot Dataframe with value of "concept" as Column & Value in rows
XML_List:

```
[{'concept': 'MEASURE', 'value': '1'}, {'concept': 'INDIGENOUS_STATUS', 'value': 'IM'}, {'concept': 'ASGS_2011', 'value': '0'}, {'concept': 'FREQUENCY', 'value': 'A'}]
```

Converting List to Dataframe:

```
XML_SeriesKey = pd.DataFrame(XML_List)

print(XML_SeriesKey)

         concept value
0            MEASURE     1
1  INDIGENOUS_STATUS    IM
2          ASGS_2011     0
3          FREQUENCY     A
```

Expected:

```
MEASURE INDIGENOUS_STATUS   ASGS_2011   FREQUENCY
1       IM                  0           A
```

Can we do it while creating Dataframe from List?

```
XML_SeriesKey = pd.DataFrame(XML_List) # Any possibility while creating Dataframe?
```

Comment: is `XML_SeriesKey.T` not what you need?

Comment: `df.set_index('concept').T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  list comprehension with `zip`:

```
v =  [(x.get('concept'), x.get('value')) for x in XML_List]
cols, vals = zip(*v)

XML_SeriesKey= pd.DataFrame([vals], columns=cols)
print(XML_SeriesKey)
  MEASURE INDIGENOUS_STATUS ASGS_2011 FREQUENCY
0       1                IM         0         A
```

Or create index from `concept` and transpose:

```
XML_SeriesKey = pd.DataFrame(XML_List).set_index('concept').T
XML_SeriesKey.columns.name = None

print(XML_SeriesKey)
        MEASURE INDIGENOUS_STATUS ASGS_2011 FREQUENCY
value         1                IM         0         A
```

Comment: In second script can we remove "concept" column ?